# I want to change column alias dynamically as current_date() in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

my query :-

select metric,
if(d1 is null,"insp_not_done",d1) as **d1**,
if(d2 is null,"insp_not_done",d2) as **d2**,
if(d3 is null,"insp_not_done",d3) as **d3**,
if(d4 is null,"insp_not_done",d4) as **d4**,
if(d5 is null,"insp_not_done",d5) as **d5**,
if(d6 is null,"insp_not_done",d6) as **d6**,
from

( select "inspection" as metric, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6 from xyz table)

Here, I want d1 as current_date "2022-02-03", d2 as current_date()-1 and like wise aliases but not able to make it dynamic as couldn't find the correct way in bigquery.
Thanks in advance for help.

output getting from query :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhkJI.png)

output required:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdyef.png)

I want d1 to be current_date as alias everytime when query runs, d2 to be current_date()-1.

Comment: please add a sample and expected o/p.

Comment: Mr.Batra,
 Added please check.

Comment: This is not helping, we need sample data too. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't think sample data is needed here, my question is in very general and common aspect, that for any query when we put alias to the column name, whether we can make dynamic alias or not. let's suppose we have an employee table I wanted department in rows and with respect to it I wanted no. of employee  joined day on day for past 10 days in columns for each day, and column name should be date of join which is dynamic date that means every time i execute my query it'll give last 10 days data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate ('''
select * except(row_id) from (
select metric, dN, current_date - N as col, row_id
from ( 
  select "inspection" as metric, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, to_json_string(t) as row_id 
  from your_table t
), unnest([
  if(d1 is null,"insp_not_done",d1), 
  if(d2 is null,"insp_not_done",d2), 
  if(d3 is null,"insp_not_done",d3), 
  if(d4 is null,"insp_not_done",d4), 
  if(d5 is null,"insp_not_done",d5), 
  if(d6 is null,"insp_not_done",d6)
]) dN with offset as N
)
pivot (min(Dn) for col in (''' ||
(select string_agg("'" || date || "'", ',' order by offset desc)
from unnest(generate_date_array(current_date - 5, current_date)) date with offset) || "))"
)
```

if apply to dummy data like in below example

```
create temp table your_table as (
  select '1' d1, null d2, '3' d3, '4' d4, null d5, '6' d6 union all
  select '21' d1, '22' d2, null d3, '24' d4, '25' d5, '26' d6   
);
```

output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are tradeoff in what you expect. Firstly, you can't use `-` in your column label, only `_`. Secondly, you can't start your column label by a number. Lastly, you can't run a function as column alias.

But, there is a solution.

In fact, you have to write a script and to create your query with the correct aliases, and then to execute your query. Here a dummy example

```sql
declare query string;
set query= "select 1 as " || FORMAT_DATE("_%Y_%m_%d", CURRENT_DATE()) ;
execute immediate query;
```

The result is
[image]

It's the closer than what you want that I can propose